# Python Regex not Acting Properly

Tags: python, regex, search, line, newline

I am trying to search for  a chromosome number the begins on a new line.  Here is the relevant code:

```
chrp = re.compile(r"^chr[^\t]+", re.MULTILINE)
for v in vcfs:
    vcffile = open(v, "r")
    vcf = vcffile.read()
    last_i = 0
    while chrp.search(vcf, last_i) is not None:
        find = chrp.search(vcf, last_i).group()  #next chrom
        print find
        last_i = vcf.index(find, last_i)  #index of chrom
        print vcf[last_i:10 + last_i]
```

However, this prints out:

```
chr1
chr19/snps
```

The problems with this are:

1) "chr19/snps..." isn't on a new line, it is in the middle of a line after a slash

2) Even if it was on a new line, the regex only matches "chr1" where it should match "chr19/sn...." until the next tab

Here is a snippet of where it is finding this:

`4186561/variants/chr19/snps.g`

Here is an example of what I want it to find:

`chr19` in the line `chr19  18272190` or `chrX` in the line `chrX   13758375`

I have tried using https://pythex.org/ and it works fine there.

Comment: Please indent code with four spaces. The backticks are to be used in a line, like this: `foo`.

Comment: Where is `18272190` in your input?

Comment: Both of those issues are fixed now, sorry. @Tichodroma that is just part of the line, I don't actually want to find it.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behaviour you describe. Could you perhaps put some more lines in a pastebin? Also, why not just read the file line by line?

Comment: @Jerry I ended up just reading it line by line.  Unfortunately, I deleted the old code so I cannot repost it even though I still would have liked to know what went wrong.